# CSS selector for :before pseudo-element when there is one class but NOT another class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, css-selectors, radio-button

I am working with Bootstrap to create a user interface where amongst other things I want to enhance the appearance of radio buttons by ensuring that a checkmark appears prior to the selected radio option.  No problem I thought - a simple spot of CSS should do it.  So I tried

```
.active:before{font-family:gftm;content:'\e844';padding-right:0.2em;}
```

where `gftm` happens to be my own Fontello generated font.  This worked but it introduced an unexpected problem.  I am also using [Bootstrap toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) buttons in this particular application which in their `off` state use the classes `active toggle-off` which ends up showing a spurious and misleading checkmark prior to the button text in its off state.  I tried fixing this by modifying my CSS rule

```
.active:before:not(.toggle-off){font-family:gftm;content:'\e844';padding-right:0.2em;}
```

which did little other than stop the checkmarks appearing altogether.  The solution I am using right now is to follow the rule above with an additional rule

```
.toggle-off:before{content:'' !important;}
```

However, I suspect that there is probably a neater way of doing this with just the one CSS rule.  I'd be much obliged to anyone who might be able to suggest one that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is correct and it should produce the required output except for a small mistake that you have made in the selector. The below is ***how you had written*** it:

```
.active:before:not(.toggle-off) {
  font-family: gftm;
  content: '\e844';
  padding-right: 0.2em;
}
```

but the problem is that pseudo-element selector (`:before`) must appear at the end and not before the negation pseudo-class.

The below is what [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements) says about pseudo-elements and their area of presence:

> Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector, and ***if present it must appear after the sequence of simple selectors*** that represents the subjects of the selector.

The below is what the [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors#simple-selector) says about ***simple selectors***:

> A simple selector is either a type selector or universal selector followed immediately by zero or more attribute selectors, ID selectors, ***or pseudo-classes,*** in any order.

<sup>(emphasis is mine in both the quoted texts)</sup>

The [***negation (`:not`) is a pseudo-class***](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation) and so is a simple selector. This means that the `:before` cannot appear before it.

---

In the below snippet, you'd see how it works when the pseudo-element is at the end.

```css
.active:before {
  content: 'Pseudo';
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.active:not(.toggle-off):before { /* this will work */
  color: red;
}
.active:before:not(.toggle-off) { /* this won't work */
  background: beige;
}
```

```html
<div class='active'>Actual</div>
<div class='active toggle-off'>Actual</div>
<div class='toggle-off'>Actual</div>
<div class=''>Actual</div>
```

Comment: Wow!  Now that is what I call a scholarly and comprehensive answer.  Thank you very much!